# create a simple digital timer in android

Tags: android, timer

I'm basically looking to just keep track of seconds and minutes starting at 0:00 from when the app starts, and display it in a TextView what would be the best method of doing this?

Comment: I had to implement something similar, and found the [following](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html) android developer blog post helpful. All the best.

Comment: i cant seem to get that code to do anything.  it has me create 2 onClick listeners, mStartListener & mStopListener, but the code doesn't show them being attached to anything.  when i attached mStartListener to a button, it updates once, with some weird number then thats it.  do you still have your code you used for doing that?  thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

As timer starts a non-UI Thread, i'll prefer not to use it for updating TextView. In your case Timer can be replaced by the Handler class. And you can also avoid the overhead of this new non-UI thread. [Here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html) is an example:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

OnClickListener mStartListener = new OnClickListener() 
{
   public void onClick(View v)
   {
      if (mStartTime == 0L) 
      {
        mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
      }
   }
};

.........

private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() 
{
   public void run() 
   {
     final long start = mStartTime;
     long millis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
     int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
     int minutes = seconds / 60;
     seconds     = seconds % 60;

     if (seconds < 10) 
     {
        mTimeLabel.setText("" + minutes + ":0" + seconds);
     } 
     else 
     {
        mTimeLabel.setText("" + minutes + ":" + seconds);            
     }

     mHandler.postAtTime(this,start + (((minutes * 60) + seconds + 1) * 1000));
   }
};
```

Comment: This answer is probably wrong as `currentTimeMillis` will return time since 1970 hence value of `millis` will be in negative

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) to schedule a [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) each second.

- first you take the beginning time
- then in the TimerTask job you get the time spent (`beginning time - current time`)
- you format this difference as a String of the form xx:xx with [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html)
- you update the TextView with this String

I'm not sure if you could have problems when updating the TextView from the TimerTask job as it doesn't run in UI thread, in that case you can use [Activity.runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to do this

Answer (score 2):

```
    Runnable run = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime;
               int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
               int minutes = (seconds%3600)/60;
               int hours = seconds / 3600;
               seconds     = seconds % 60;

               et1.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",hours, minutes, seconds));
     //          et2.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",hours, minutes, seconds));
      //         et3.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",hours, minutes, seconds));

               h2.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }
    };

    class firstTask extends TimerTask {

        public void run() {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
};
```

try it in ur program...!